# IS equation in a DSGE: interpretation

Tags: open-economy-macro, dsge

I am solving a DSGE model and I derived the following expression for the IS equation:

[image]

However, I have some problems interpreting this equation. How would you interpret it?

[image] is the domestic output

[image] is the expectation of domestic output

[image] the expectation of domestic inflation

[image] the real interest rate

[image] a time discount rate

[image] measures the substitutability between goods produced in different foreign
countries.

[image] is simply given by the product of the other paramters such as gamma, etc

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: can you add further information about the definition of E{yt+1} and E{d y*t+1}? I suspect your interpretation of delta y star might be wrong or at least missing something?